# Calculation of Cutting forces (tangential , feed and normal) in CNC Milling Process

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cnc, tools, cutting, forces

**I am doing my fyp project on 5 axis cnc milling machine.I need to calculate forces on each axis** as mentioned in the below picture

[image]

I first calculated spindle power from https://www.machiningdoctor.com/ and from that i calculate Ft. i read from https://www.mmsonline.com/articles/a-new-milling-101-milling-forces-and-formulas that there is 70% Ft and 20% Ff and 10% Fp. These are my calculations

[image]

[image]

[image]

book is from Manufacturing Automation Metal Cutting Mechanics, Machine Tool Vibrations, and CNC Design Second Edition By Yusuf Altintas.

**Can someone please confirm if my calculations are correct and if I can apply same logic for z-axis calculation or should i use drilling equation instead(if yes then how forces are related with each other)?**

Comment: Please don't upload text as images.

Comment: https://www.keyence.com/ss/products/measure-sys/machining/formula/cutting.jsp